# What are the forces behind the orbit of the Earth around the Sun?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, solar-system, celestial-mechanics

Does the gravity of the sun alone affect the orbit of the earth around the sun?

Look at the image below,**(Image is not to scale)**,

[image]

Is it that when earth is going from position 1 to position 2, it speeds up due to the pull of the sun, goes around the sun and when going from points 2 to 1 again slows down due to the gravity of the sun? Does the velocity of the earth around the sun vary depending upon whether it is going away or nearing the sun?

Comment: "Does the gravity of the sun alone affect the orbit of the earth around the sun?" As a practical matter, yes. But, in principle, everything in the universe affects it, albeit only  to an imperceptible degree. Other sources are negligible relative to the Sun because the Sun accounts for 99.85% of the mass in the solar system. The eight non-dwarf planets account for about 0.135% of the mass in the solar system (more than two-thirds of which is in the planet Jupiter which is also more distant from Earth than the Sun by a factor of two to four). The mass of the Sun is about 333,000 times Earth's.

Comment: That picture is kind of wonky, by the way. If it's meant to illustrate a highly elliptical orbit (viewed from straight above the orbital plane), then the Sun is way too far from the point labelled 2 (which should be the closest point of the orbit to the Sun). If it's instead meant to be a semi-realistic depiction of the Earth's (almost circular) orbit, but viewed at an angle, then the Sun is way too close to point 2 instead.

Comment: *"Does the velocity of the earth around the sun vary depending upon whether it is going away or nearing the sun?"* The speed just depends on the distance between them. See Kepler's 3rd law. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion

Comment: Universe, Space, Solar system and everything are total lie. Four questions to everyone who beLIEve: 1. If the sun can pull neptune, then why it can't pull our moon which is much closer when it's between earth and the sun? 2. If earth & atmosphere spin 1000mph eastwardly then flights cannot reach westward destination, but it can, WHY? 3. If earth goes around the sun then for 6 months we should see completely other stars on other side but 12 months same stars, WHY? 4. If the sun is behind earth at night then WHY mercury and venus show up in night sky?

Comment: @Ĭsααctիεβöss What are you hoping to accomplish here? There are tons of great resources (many freely available) on basic physics and orbital mechanics, but since you're ignoring them, I don't think you've come here to be informed, just to argue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it does. Your description is correct. Other bodies than the Sun also pull in Earth with their respective gravities, though, but they are effectively negligible.

The elliptic effect is not as pronounced as you illustrate here, though. Earth's orbit is close to circular.

- When **closest**, the Sun-Earth distance is around 147 million km.
- When **farthest**, around 152 million km.

[image]
<sup>From [Britannica: Astronomy](https://www.britannica.com/science/orbit-astronomy)</sup>

(This image is still not circular enough; see comments. The actual drawn orbit would most likely be impossible to distinguish from a perfectly circular orbit.)

That corresponds to orbital speeds of

- ~$30 \;\mathrm{km/s}$ when fastest and
- ~$29.3 \;\mathrm{km/s}$ when slowest

(according to [Ask an Astronomer](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/about-us/41-our-solar-system/the-earth/orbit/85-how-fast-does-the-earth-go-at-perihelion-and-aphelion-intermediate); I didn't plug in the numbers myself, but that shouldn't be a big deal to do to verify this).

Comment: Actually, even your picture, although coming from Encyclopedia Britannica, is too much elliptic. A real drawing of the orbit of the Earth is hardly distinguishable from a an exact circle.

Comment: The position of farthest distance is about 3.25% farther away than the closest.

Comment: Also, the Sun and the Earth are both _way_ too large in that picture.

Comment: Also, there are no arrows and dotted lines in space. Also the Sun isn't really labeled and there are way too many Earths in the picture. Let's just accept that it's a not-to-scale illustration instead of a photograph.

Comment: Thanks, all, for the corrective comments; I have added an edit to clarify the inaccuracy of the image. And thanks @Moyli for having my back 

Comment: Does the variance affect the weather on earth?  When we're 3% farther away, does that mean it's colder here?   And with our wobble, is the same part of earth always closest/farthest at that position in the orbit?

Comment: @Keith It must affect the weather. Because radiation intensity goes with the square of the distance, a 3% distance difference results in a 6% radiation difference. I could not immediately find a good reference though (all sites are so concerend that people think the distance is responsible for the seasons).

Comment: I always understood the cause for the seasons to be the tilt of the earth.   I'm curious if the tilt is always the same at that point in the orbit, or does it vary, resulting in an unusually warm or cold winter.

Comment: @Peter Yes, it makes a difference to the amount of solar radiation we receive, so that southern hemisphere seasons should be more extreme than the northern ones. However, the 2 hemispheres aren't identical in their distribution of land masses, and that makes things more complicated. Also, we have a cold circumpolar current here in the south.

Comment: @Keith Changes in the eccentricity (elliptical-ness) of the Earth's orbit are one of the Milankovitch Cycles that contribute to ice ages, so it does make a small difference that can add up to a big difference when combined with other factors over a long period of time. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milankovitch_cycles]

Answer (score 0):

Just speaking generically, if you have a mass orbiting a star, then yes, the velocity of the object increases when it is closer to the host star than when the radius of its orbit is farther away.  I imagine the picture is just a generic example and exaggerating an ellipse.  It has to do with conservation of angular momentum.

It works the same for all masses in a system.  So, comets, moons, planets, whatever... they all do it.